# Passing data between view controllers in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, view, controller

I currently have a table view controller filled with data.

This table view controller leads to a Display view controller which displays the info with the selected data.

I've used a prepareForSegue to send the selected data to the next view controller.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showInfo"]) {


        NSManagedObject *selectedData = [self.datas objectAtIndex:[[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row]];
        DisplayInfoViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.data = selectedData;
    }
}
```

My problem is that now I've added another view controller (Display More Info View Controller) after that view controller.

tableVC > DisplayVC >DisplayMoreInfoVC

I am having problems passing the same selected data over into the next view controller as my first prepareForSegue gets the selected data from the selected row of the table which i cannot access in the DisplayVC.

Any ideas?

Comment: I dont get it, if you have all your Data in DisplayVC (because you passed from tableVC) why you just dont pass it from DisplayVC to DisplayMoreInfoVC ?

Comment: I have been trying to do that but as i am new to iOS development, it just doesnt seem to work....I cant see what i am doing wrong..

Comment: NSManagedObject *selectedData = [self.database **getdatapassedpreviously**];
        DisplayMoreInfoViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.data = selectedData;   This is the code i am currently working on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you query the database in the dispayVC   Are you passing the same data that you received from tableVC to DisplayMoreInfoViewController?  If yes then you can just do

```
 DisplayMoreInfoViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
 destViewController.data = self.data
```

If it is different the exlplain a little bite more what is

```
[self.database getdatapassedpreviously];
```

Comment: I was trying that before but giving me an exception...for some reason it now works :S Thanks