# how to pass data b/w two view controllers?

Tags: ios, objective-c

i am new in ios development .

i have two view controllers .

```
-(IBAction)clickToview:(id)sender
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"1" sender:self];   
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
        second *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

        destViewController.labA.text=textA.text;  // here i want to set values in labA to labB. in second view .
        destViewController.labB.text=textB.text;

        NSLog(@"labA ");
    }
}

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    textA.text=@"London ";  // this is my text fields 
    textB.text=@"Dreams ";

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: Believe or not, there several duplicates with **the exact same title.** I can't imagine you couldn't have found at least one of them if you had actually used Google or the site search.

Comment: Also, this has nothing to do with Xcode -- this is a language/algorithm/API question, and it wouldn't be different if you used `make` and `emacs` for writing your iOS application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [passing data between view controllers iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17536760/passing-data-between-view-controllers-ios) and [Passing Data between View Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Comment: @H2CO3 - Wouldn't be that different if you were writing in C++ or C#, for that matter.

Comment: @HotLicks This would only be related to Xcode if the question was "how to do it in Interface Builder instead of by writing code" IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In story Board you can send value one view to another view like Bellow way. Your Implement method did Wrong.

in you **Second view-controller** you need to define NSString with `property` and sythsize it.

**.h class**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *YourString;
```

**.m Class**

```
@synthesize YourString;
```

Now you can use it like:-

```
-(IBAction)youMethod:(id)sender
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"secondview" sender:self];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
            if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"secondview"]) {
         secondviewcontroller *controller = segue.destinationViewController
                controller.YourString = @"myValue";
             }

}
```